# Django HTML Send POST data to url as PK value when submitting

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I have a form that's just a date field and submit button

Forms.py

```
from django import forms
from datetime import date

class DateInput(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'

class HomeForm(forms.Form):
    EnterDate = forms.DateField(widget=DateInput, initial=date.today())
```

Because of a user request, I just want to send the data to the url like this

home/2021-07-01

so I tried to do this for my html form, just stick the **form.EnterDate.value** in the form Action part, but it only works on the 2nd try.

```
<form method="POST" class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'mint-post' form.EnterDate.value  %}">
{% csrf_token %}


<label for="{{form.EnterDate.id_for_label}}">Enter Date</label>
{{form.EnterDate}}

<button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Submit Date</button>
```

```
#Inital loading the form
def mintHome(request):
    form = HomeForm()

    context = {
        'form': form }
    return render(request, 'mintyHome.html', context)
    
#after Post   
 def mintHomePost(request, pk):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            datePost = form.cleaned_data['EnterDate']
            stringDate = datePost.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    context = {
        'form': form }
    return render(request, 'mintyHome.html', context)
```

I made an example here:

https://alisayt.pythonanywhere.com/minty/home

It sends the form.EnterDate.value only in the 2nd submit, but not the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the POST request to be sent to a URL based on the current date? Or to a URL based on the user input?

The template code `{% url 'mint-post' form.EnterDate.value  %}` is only executed once on the server when you request the page, not when you change the date input and submit the POST request.

If you would like the action URL to change with the user input, this has to happen on the client side, i. e. using JavaScript.